# How to capture video from youtube and output it to a certain formatted local file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write implement a chrome extension that can capture video from youtube and output to certain formatted local file, like mp3.

I found this [post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream) that shows I can call captureStream() to capture the video from  with which youtube delivers video.

But I am looking for a way to output var stream = leftVideo.captureStream(); to a local mp4 file. Did lots of research on this second step, but made no progress. Need some help. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: I would find a similar extension and examine its code.